# Progress Bar not showing up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm learning to use fragments in Android and I'm using one to display an image which is being downloaded from an URL, which is why I need the progress bar. However, once I execute the app, the progress bar doesn't show up before the image is displayed.

This is my xml for the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstFragmentImageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/firstFragmentProgressBar"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></FrameLayout>
```

and this is the function where I'm making visible the progress bar while downloading the image:

```
private fun loadImageUsingGlide(){
    firstFragmentProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    Glide.with(this).asBitmap()
            .load(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
            .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(firstFragmentImageView){
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    super.onResourceReady(resource, transition)
                    firstFragmentProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                }
            })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. Don't know why, but changing the tag of the progress bar from

```
<android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
```

to simply

```
<ProgressBar
```

made it work